# Can I blend or get rid of null pixels in my images?

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

Using opencv, I'm detecting circles in my images.

I get the "Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat" error. Other questions with this error mentioned null pixels, which some of my pictures do have. Can I get rid of the null pixels before the function where the error happens executes?

Additionally, I've been able to run the bit of code on the images with null pixels before. This error is only occurring when I try to it over a set of images with a for loop.

```
for i in range (1, 9):
    filename = 'motrans/motrans_images_june/AMR' + str(i) + '.png'
    img = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
    img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 1)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 300, param1=60, param2=20, minRadius=55, maxRadius=75) #3
```

The error occurs at cv2.HoughCircles.

Comment: What is a "null pixel"? Could you attach the image you're having trouble with, so other can try to reproduce this? Are you sure that `imread` didn't fail to load the image? You never seem to actually test the result before you use it...